# Android: Motorola MC40 device not recognized for debugging app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, motorola

I am trying to run an app for debugging using the android SDK in eclipse for the Motorola MC40 device but the device will not show up in the android device chooser when I run the app with the device connected. I have successfully ran the app on a samsung galaxy 7.

I have followed the instructions for setting up a device for debugging on the android website: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html. and I entered the correct vendor id for Motorola. However, the device will still not show up when I try to run the app. Please help.

Comment: What version of Android is on your MC40?  Make sure you have set your minimum target to that version in your manifest.

Comment: Its version 2.3.4 and I changed the min target version to that version and it still didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.

For anyone having the same issue:
The Problem for the motorola MC40 is that the Vendor ID number is not the same as the Motorola vendor Id number (22b8). The MC40 vendor ID is "05e0". That was the root of the problem. So when following the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) make sure to enter the ID mentioned heretofore. Also not only do you have to add the id to the "51-android.rules" file in this format ("SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05e0", MODE="0666", OWNER="[user_name]"), but you also have to add the HEX  version of the ID (0x5e0) to the "adb_usb.ini" file in .android directory: ~/.android/.

Comment: Do you know if the Motorola XT316 has the same issue? But I can get the device online eventually, but most of times is offline.

Comment: The MC40 is a Motorola Solution device (now Zebra Technologies) and the USB Vendor ID used by this device is 0x05E0 (assigned to Symbol Technologies, that has been acquired by Motorola around 2007/2008).

Answer (score 0):

For reference here is the official Android USB Windows installer for Motorola/Symbol Android devices:

https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=95914